# Executing JavaScript client written code on server side of an application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am currently developing a web application equipped with a web-based code editor for JavaScript. The scope of this project is to allow users to execute JS code from the client-side of the application, using some server-side variables that differ based on the logged user(For feature testing purposes). The client application runs on React and the server-side runs on NodeJS. I have bumped into three different concepts of execution:

1. Saving the code into a `.js` file and sending it to the server for execution.
2. Saving the code into some kind of variable and converting it back into raw code in the server-side, then executing it.
3. Requesting the server data then executing a JS code snippet on the client-side of the application(Seems safest but least possible).

The JS code won't need to be equipped with the capability to import libraries or call other local files, its main purpose is to test and create mathematical and logical algorithms based on specific variables. What are some good ways to execute such a non-native code?

Comment: I would execute client side otherwise I don't know how you can keep it safe. Also what's the point executing it server side ?

Comment: Despite the main purpose being to execute mathematical and logical algorithms, it is a bad idea to execute untrusted code on your server. You could always send the code to the server, insert the special values, then send it back to the client to be executed.

Comment: Thank you, I had a similar idea, but my proficiency with React is not that strong and thus I didn't know if it was possible.

Comment: @ValioRaltchev I don't know whether this will work, which is why it's just a comment, but could you send the script to the server, then get a URL back from the server which will return the script with the values in it replaced? In React, you then create a `<script>` tag that points to the URL returned by the server.

Answer (score 1):

Way 1: use eval, for ex:

```
axios.get('api.js', data => {
  eval(data.data);
});
```

way 2: You can wrap your new JS to a function

```
const {randomString)Function  = () => { 
       // you code 
}
```